# Ansible task to create user with looping and checks

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to create a task where I can set up users based in a group of environments and types of servers when I'm running a task for that specific env and server.
For example, let's say I'm running the playbook in the oracle servers for production, the task should only add the user1 and not user2.

So I've set this way the vars:

```
"internal_users": [
  {
    "username": user1,
    "comment": "Name of the User",
    "password": "$1$D3d32t4t53y5ytyttgtuudhkjfgt!fdfsdf.",
    "env": ["prod","uat"],
    "hosts": ["apache","oracle"]
  },
  {
    "username": user2,
    "comment": "Name of the User2",
    "password": "$1$D3d32t4t53y5fdfvrgrt45234fdfsdf.",
    "env": ["uat"],
    "hosts": ["apache","oracle"]
  }
]
```

I believe I can get the actual env and server that I'm running the playbook using the var `vars['env']` for environment and `inventory_hostname`.

Then the task:

```
- name: Create Internal users
  vars: 
    env: "{{ vars['env'] }}"
    host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
  user:
    name: "{{ item.username }}"
    comment: "{{ item.comment }}"
    groups: wheel,internal_users
    append: yes
    shell: /bin/bash
    password: "{{ item.password }}"
    update_password: on_create
  when: env in item.hosts
  with_dict: "{{ internal_users }}"
```

It isn't working, could someone help with the logic to make it work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable "internal_users" is a list not a dictionary. "loop" must be used instead of "with_dict". For example, the task running on "oracle"

```
    - name: Create Internal users
      debug:
        msg:
          - "{{ item.username }}"
          - "{{ item.comment }}"
          - "{{ item.password }}"
      loop: "{{ internal_users }}"
      when:
        - env in item.env
        - host in item.hosts
      vars: 
        env: uat
        host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

gives

```
    "msg": [
        "user1", 
        "Name of the User", 
        "$1$D3d32t4t53y5ytyttgtuudhkjfgt!fdfsdf."
    ]

    "msg": [
        "user2", 
        "Name of the User2", 
        "$1$D3d32t4t53y5fdfvrgrt45234fdfsdf."
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final task working:

```
- name: Create Internal users
  vars: 
    env: "{{ vars['env'] }}"
    host: "{{ group_names[0] }}"
  user:
    name: "{{ item.username }}"
    comment: "{{ item.comment }}"
    groups: wheel,internal_users
    append: yes
    shell: /bin/bash
    password: "{{ item.password }}"
    update_password: on_create
  when:
    - env in item.env
    - host in item.hosts
  loop: "{{ internal_users }}"
```

Thanks to Vladimir Botka for the help.